# How to merge 2 columnar matrices into a row matrix?

Tags: matrix

if i have two columnar matrices A,B . then how can i merge both matrices into a row matrix.

```
         A =  {-0.157681 - 0.0140601 I, 0.987384 + 0. I, 0.0000372277 - 0.00334827 I,-0.000272331 + 0.000439789 I}  ;
         B =  {0.991357 + 0. I, -0.130103 - 0.0163991 I, -0.000272562 + 0.000624515 I, 0.0000254395 - 0.00390685 I } ;
         Matrix = ( {{A, B}} )
```

Which gives me output
[image]

i want to know how to  remove the brackets inside the matrix. and i also want to  know whether removing of these brackets effect the matrix.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen `Join[]`?

Comment: yes you are right dear , but Join [ A,B,2]; will solve it but , i want to some other methods

Comment: Then you should have mentioned it in your question to begin with, bub.

Comment: You can use `Transpose[Flatten/@{A,B}]`, and I'm sure we could come up with an infinite number of convoluted variations. But why do you not want to use the method J.M. gave? If you have a particular performance goal in mind you might get better answers.

Comment: LMAO @ bub.   I can't help but notice you asked this question 2 hours ago and got two workable solutions in the comments

Comment: Don't forget `ArrayFlatten[{{A, B}}]` and `Thread[Flatten /@ {A, B}]`

Comment: Jason B  if i replace the value with iota then these commands does't work

Comment: Then include those examples that don't work in your question!

Answer (score 3):

```
A = ({{-0.157681 - 0.0140601 I}, {0.987384 + 0. I}, {0.0000372277 - 
      0.00334827 I}, {-0.000272331 + 0.000439789 I}});
B = ({{0.991357 + 0. I}, {-0.130103 - 0.0163991 I}, {-0.000272562 + 
      0.000624515 I}, {0.0000254395 - 0.00390685 I}});
```

This is a good point to say that working with column vectors in *Mathematica* is more trouble than it is worth - you just don't need to do it most of the time.  If your `A` and `B` were normal row vectors, then all you need is `Transpose[{A,B}]`.  Here are ways that you can work with these column vectors to make a matrix.

```
Join[A, B, 2] // MatrixForm
ArrayFlatten[{{A, B}}] // MatrixForm
Transpose[Flatten /@ {A, B}] // MatrixForm
Thread[Flatten /@ {A, B}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

And then, if you want to do it the old-timey way (this is how it feels when I have to work in Fortran)

```
AB = ConstantArray[0.0, {4, 2}];
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
  AB[[i, 1]] = A[[i, 1]];
  AB[[i, 2]] = B[[i, 1]];
  ];
AB // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Jason B  Thanks for this value able but my input occur with single bracket around A,B.

Comment: Please Jason B see it again

Comment: And so how is `Transpose[{A, B}]` not working for you?

Comment: :P it works    Thanks a lot Dear